# Python kdtree find "n" nearest neighboring groups (of coordinates)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

**Objective**: Given a coordinate X, find "n" nearest line-polygon for coordinate X, not just "n" nearest points. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIWTW.png

---

I have a group of spatial line-polygons which can have more than 2 coordinates. Their coordinates are stored in a (scipy)KDtree to enable NN search.

First, I will query "i" number of nearest coordinates then look up the corresponding line-polygons-> "i" coordinates may not necessarily produce "i" lines.

In order to achieve "n" nearest lines, I will need to increase "i". My problem is that "i" can be unpredictable because the number of coords varies between every line-polygon. Example, a line-polygon can be represented by 2 coordinates, but another can be represented using 10 coordinates. Most of the time, I only need 2 nearest neighboring line-polygons from point X.

In the example image, I need line A and B as my result. Even with "i" = 3, only line A will be found because A1, A2, A3 are the nearest neighbors to X.

---

**Question**: Is there a way to group coordinates of a shape together and then carry out NN search to get "n" unique shapes? (besides brute forcing "i" to ensure "n" unique shapes)

---

Current workaround pseudocode:

```
found = []
while True:
    if first_loop:
        result = look up N nearest coords
    else:
        result = look up Nth nearest coord

    look up shapes using result and append to found
    perform de-duplication of found

    if len(found) >= required:
         return found
    else:
         N = N+1 # to check the Nth neighbor next iteration
```

Comment: Would transforming your groups into "average/mid points" make sense? So, you would translate your problem into point NN, match k nearest points, and then expand those matches into original groups.

Comment: Hi randomir, I thought of representing every shape using single coordinates too. However, my geo-spatial shapes also vary in size thus using centroids for nearest neighbors may not give desire outcome (I only need at most 4 for every query). 

Imagine a star shape road network where I'm in the centre and there are 5 roads (shapes) branching out. Technically, the distance between 5 roads and I are the same. But if we use centroids as reference, road length will matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly, it's a problem of having the right data-structures.

Let's have the following data-structures,
 1. A dictionary from the line-polygons to points
 2. Another dictionary from points to line-polygons (or equivalently a single bidirectional map from bidict instead of couple of dictionaries)
 3. a boolean array *visited* with size equal to the number of points

Now the following algorithm should solve your problem (can be implemented efficiently with the above data structures):

1. For all the points initialize the visited array to be False.
2. Find the nearest point to the query point first from the kd-tree, mark the matched point and all the points from the the corresponding polygon the matched point belongs to as visited and return that particular polygon (id) as the nearest polygon (if there are multiple such polygons, return all of them).
3. Repeat step 2 until n such (distinct) polygons are returned. Consider a new point returned from the kd-tree as matched with the query point iff it's not yet visited (if a matched point returned by kd-tree is already visited, discard it and query the next nearest point matched). Once a point is visited, mark the point and all the points from the corresponding polygon(s) as visited and return the polygon(s).

Comment: Hi @Sandipan, yes you are right, this is more of an algorithm and data-structure problem. In my current implementation, I do have #1 and #2. I was trying to avoid #3 boolean array because that is brute forcing. I will detail my work around (which is quite similar to yours) in my question. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of doing this efficiently:

1. Index the complete "line-polygons": For this you could bound each line-polygon by a minimum bounding rectangle. Then index all the rectangles with an appropriate index structure like an [R-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree). Instead of points, you will have line-polygons on the lowest level, so you will have to adapt the distance for this case.
2. Use [Distance Browsing](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.386.8193&rep=rep1&type=pdf): The idea here is to attach to each point the id of its line-polygon and index the points in an index structure (e.g., KD-Tree). Then you successively retrieve the next nearest point to your query using distance browsing. You proceed this until you have found points of n different line-polygons.

Comment: Hi @SaiBot, thank you for your answer: |
1. I understand that rtree can used to store spatial index (bounding rectangle) of shapes and can be used quickly to find possible intersection. You are proposing to increase the the size of this bounding rectangles so that they can intersect with point X later on? I could consider bounding point X instead. | 
2. Thanks for the reference. It looks complex though I understand your explanation. I'm looking for a library which allows this attachment. Otherwise, a manual implementation is needed similar to Sandipan Dey's answer below.

Comment: 1. You cannot only find intersections with an R-Tree but also nearest neighbours. You do not have to increase the size of rectangles! 2. The paper looks complex but the idea is really simple: You have to build a min-heap where points and rectangles (e.g., KD-Tree nodes) are stored by minimum distance to the query X. Then you insert the root node of your index. Whenever you remove an entry from the heap, you reinsert the children. When you retrieve a point you got the next nearest neighbour.

Comment: Interesting! I'm a bit pressed for time and had to go with the current work around but will definitely try out your suggestions. Thank you! :)